# Problem of using class and id while removeChild from parent

Tags: javascript, html

i saw this example and trying to understand the theory behind the html
if i use class in  and id in

why it doesn't work. why i cant remove the child element it gives me error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    var child = document.getElementById("p1");
    parent.removeChild(child);
};

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo"> 
            <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
            <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but if i index parent node it work! i want to know how it work

```
var parent =document.getElementById("p1");
    parent[0].removeChild(child);
```

Comment: code is wrong parent will be a collection, not single element. change to `var parent = document.querySelector(".demo");`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. There is not `removeChild` on the `HTMLCollection` object.

Comment: It's all good bud.

Comment: `it gibes me error` - what error? Edit your question, show us the error.

Comment: so class name will be string and search all class to match string by letters and return class collection ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, corrected to select single elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
    var parent = document.querySelector(".demo");
    var child = parent.querySelector("#p1");
    parent.removeChild(child);
};

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo"> 
            <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
            <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Access element by `className`

[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will collect ***All*** elements with the given class. A single target can be selected if you use the bracket notation and the index number of the specific element. The following example will get the first (or only) element with the given class:

> ```
> var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0];
> ```

Or

> ```
> var parent = document.querySelector('.demo');
> ```

Note the syntax for the given parameter of [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method:

> **'.demo'**                **'#p1'**                        **'div'**                             **'[name=radio]'**
>
>  the dot prefix     the hash prefix       if there's no prefix   this syntax denotes an
>
> denotes a `class`  denotes an `id`        it's a `tagName`              `attribute`

---

### Demo

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0];

/* OR this line below */
// var parent = document.querySelector('.demo');

var child = document.getElementById("p1");

parent.removeChild(child);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo"> 
            <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
            <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so class name will be string and search all class to match string by letters and return class collection ? as i given only one class but parent return class collection will it still be object array with only one class collection?

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` will return a collection by reference of  a string parameter. This array-like object is called a **HTMLCollection**. You can access a specific element of that collection with bracket notation: `var HTMLCol = document..getElementsByClassName('CLASSNAME')`  99% of the time you'll want the first element: `HTMLCol[0]`, or the 4th: `HTMLCol[3]`, or the last: `HTMLCol[HTMLCol.length -1]`, and so on. The other method: `.querySelector()` will return the first one on the page. So in short, [Continued...]

Comment: [...Continue] there are 3 types of string parameters used in DOM methods that I can think of ATM: 1. The oldest type is used by the majority of DOM methods: ex. `.getElementsByClassName()`, `.getElementById()`, `.getElementsByTagName()`, etc. The 2nd type is a `htmlString` which is a string that represents HTML markup that can be parsed into real HTML by properties like `.innerHTML` and methods like `insertAdjacentHTML()`, and the third type of string parameter (and newest) is the CSS Selector used by `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` See answer describing CSS Selector syntax.